# Getting error: "You must be logged in. Use `npm login` and try again." when trying to publish with NP

Tags: node.js, npm, np

I have a classic js package that I created and I added [NP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/np) to manage the publishment flow, but for some reason when I execute `npm run np` command, I'm getting the following error:

```bash
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://registry.yarnpkg.com
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

But I'm already signed in and if I execute `npm publish` it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue.

I removed `np` from my dependencies list and installed it **globally**

Then with any package manager I used, it worked fine.

Here's what my *package.json* script looks like:

```json
// ...
"scripts": {
  "release": "npm run prepare && np"
}
```

```bash
# whit yarn
yarn run release

# whit npm
npm run release

# whit pnpm
pnpm run release
```

Answer (score 2):

This won't help the original poster, but for anyone else who stumbles across this and is using `yarn` to kick off the `np` script, try using `npm run` instead. This was the problem I had and using `npm run` fixed it.

So, for example:

```
# not this
yarn release

# but this instead
npm run release
```

(Assuming your release script is called `release`.)

Comment: Yes, agree.
But I was already logged and was receiving the same error :(